# Plotting a boxplot against multiple factors in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a function that plots (I think) various conditions within a set of motor racing timing data using boxplot:

```
library(RCurl)

gsqAPI = function(key, query, gid=0){
                  return(
                    read.csv( paste( sep="",'http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?', 'tqx=out:csv','&tq=', curlEscape(query), '&key=', key, '&gid=', curlEscape(gid) ) )
                    ) }
pd=gsqAPI('0AmbQbL4Lrd61dHVNemlLLWNaZ1NzX3JhaS1DYURTZVE',
          'select A,C,E,G', gid='6')

boxplot(Time~Stint*Session*DriverNum,
        data=subset(pd, (DriverNum==1 | DriverNum==2)&Time<110),
        las=2, ylab="Time(s)", xlab="FP Stint:Session:DriverNum",
        ylim=c(80,110), main='F1 2011 Italy FP Times (Red Bull)')
```

What's the equivalent way of doing this using `ggplot2`? (That is, what's the `ggplot2` equivalent of the boxplot command above?)

As a second part to the question, how would I generate a separate chart using `ggplot2` that displays the boxplot overlaid with a plot of the raw data points within each condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your `data.frame` `pd`:

```
library("ggplot2")

ggplot(subset(pd, (DriverNum==1 | DriverNum==2) & Time < 110)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=interaction(Stint,Session,DriverNum,sep=":"), y=Time)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Time(s)") +
  scale_x_discrete("FP Stint:Session:DriverNum") +
  opts(title = "F1 2011 Italy FP Times (Red Bull)")
```

[image]

You can rotate the lower labels with this modification

```
ggplot(subset(pd, (DriverNum==1 | DriverNum==2) & Time < 110)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=interaction(Stint,Session,DriverNum,sep=":"), y=Time)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Time(s)") +
  scale_x_discrete("FP Stint:Session:DriverNum") +
  opts(title = "F1 2011 Italy FP Times (Red Bull)",
    axis.text.x = theme_text(angle=90))
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful - thanks:-) Interaction() was the trick I was missing...

Comment: Is it possible to also: a) explicitly set the yrange; b) overlay the raw data points on the chart?

Comment: @psych - without testing it, something like `+ geom_point() + ylim(0,XXX) ` should do the trick. You may want to set the `alpha` parameter in `geom_point()` to get some transparency so you can see the underlying box plot. I also recommend reading through http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/ as there are quite a few examples.

Comment: @Chase has it right, @psychemedia.  Adding `+ geom_point()` after the `geom_boxplot` line will add the points (the order is important; the order of the geoms defines the order they are put down in and thus what covers what).  The `ylim` call will work, or you can incorporate it into the `scale_y_continuous` call like `scale_y_continuous("Time(s)", limits=c(0,XXX))`

Comment: @Chase, Brian Great - thanks... I need to to work through some of the ggplot docs I think; the layering is quite powerful, I think, especially when you can make use of transparency too...

Comment: Wonderful, really? (I'm talking about the rendering, not the code which is fine.) IMO, it would be better to use [faceting](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/facet_grid.html) to better reflect the interaction term.

Comment: @chl, I agree faceting would be a better approach for this.  I was going to include an example of that as part of my answer, even.  However, not all combinations of stint and session are present, so `ggplot` was throwing an error.  I don't recall if this is fixed in the development version or not.